# Is there a way for me to see how much volume an application is outputting?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a computer application which will look at the volume that Spotify and discord are outputting, and balance it accordingly so that I can hear my friends, but when they're not talking, my music is louder.

This is for a windows 10 computer, I've used pycaw to get the master volume as well as modify the master volume; however, I could not find an option to get the current volume being outputted.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, ISimpleAudioVolume, IAudioEndpointVolume, IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback


def main():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    for session in sessions:
        volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(ISimpleAudioVolume)
        if session.Process and session.Process.name() == "Discord.exe":
            print("volume.GetMasterVolume(): %s" % volume.GetMasterVolume())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By doing this, I can get the maximum volume for discord (for example 1.0). However, I want to get the level of audio discord is currently outputting (for example 0.3). What would I need to replace

```py
volume.GetMasterVolume()
```

to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: [EarTrumpet](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/tree/master/EarTrumpet/DataModel/Audio) has some c# code which is able to get session volume although I don't know how to translate that to python to give proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but I figured it may help someone on their way.

You should look at the Windows Core Audio API. Part of this API are 'audio sessions' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-sessions, which are the audio sessions for the applications as they appear in the Volume Mixer, which I think are the volumes you're referring to.

There's an existing work-in-progress Python library called `pyWinCoreAudio`, but it appears to be incomplete and doesn't currently cover audio sessions (or in no way that I could fine). However, you can have a look at the open source (GPL) source code and it should be relatively straightforward to add the functionality to query the audio sessions and set their.

For example, with the part that is already working in `pyWinCoreAudio`, this is how you'd set the volume on an existing device:

```
import pyWinCoreAudio as wca

wca.AudioDevices[3].render_endpoints[0].volume.channel_levels = (-10, -10)
```

In this case, `AudioDevices[3]` happens to be my headset, and setting the volume to `(-10, -10)` sets it 10dB below max (which would be `(0, 0)` on both channels.

To list all the audio devices and their outputs on your system, you'd do something like:

```
import pyWinCoreAudio as wca

for n, d in enumerate(wca.AudioDevices):
    for rep in d.render_endpoints:
        print(f'render endpoint {n}: {rep.name} is a {rep.form_factor}')
```

But this is in relation to the actual devices, not the applications producing the audio (i.e. the audio sessions), which the library doesn't appear to expose yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is `volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()` ([source](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/blob/develop/examples/audio_endpoint_volume_example.py)).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, ISimpleAudioVolume, IAudioEndpointVolume, IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback
from ctypes import POINTER, cast
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL


def main():
    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    for session in sessions:
        if session.Process and session.Process.name() == "Discord.exe":
            print("volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel(): %s" % volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Update:**

What this code actually do is getting the current volume level of Windows (instead of the running applications') which I think is relative to what you want to achieve.

When you try this

```
print("volume.GetVolumeRange(): (%s, %s, %s)" % volume.GetVolumeRange()) # (-74.0, 0.0, 0.03125)
```

it will return the volume range of Windows (in my case -74.0 to 0.0) from low to high, i.e -74.0 represents the volume level on the computer is 0 while 0.0 represents the volume level on the computer is 100.

If you want to set this value, you can simply do:

```
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-30.0, None)
```

Comment: When running this, I always get a negative number between 0 and about -10, regardless of application, or even if there's any audio playing from that application. Any explanation for why this is, or how it works?

Comment: Check some explanation in the update. Hope that helps.