# Getting real time audio level from application in python

Tags: python, audio, volume

I'm working on a botting project (Windows 11) and need to check if application is outputting certain level of audio, which according to the threshold would trigger certain actions. Worst case scenario - it would be fine to get audio output of whole system, not only from a certain, specific scenario. To be absolutely clear, it's not the current volume level setpoint I'm looking for, but rather actual audio that is being outputted through the speakers or other device.

[Actual thing that I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crz5P.png)

I've tried researching various other posts here and on other websites but couldn't find a working example on how to achieve this. As I understand this is not achievable by pyAudio and should be done with pyWinCoreAudio - but I couldn't find an example that would work for me, not mentioning that it seems like that project is kind of abandoned and done with python 2.0. Maybe someone has done something similar?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510476/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-see-how-much-volume-an-application-is-outputting

This is the topic that I've used as an example. OP of the topic had the exact same question as me.